# correctly-rounded double-precision division

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, numerical-analysis, numerical-computing

I am using the following algorithm for double-precision division and trying to make it correctly rounded in software emulation of floating-point.
Let *a* be the dividend and *b* is the divisor.

All operations are performed in Q2.62.

Initial approximation to the reciprocal is [image].

*b/2* is the significand of *b* with its implicit bit added, and shifted one right. For what follows, when written *a* or *b* it is meant by the significand of *a* or *b* with its implicit bit added.

The [image] is approximated with `0x17504f333f9de6` (`0x5D413CCCFE779800` in Q2.62).

After, the reciprocal is approximated with Newton-Raphson iterations:
[image]

There are 6 such iterations for the reciprocal, *r*. The quotient, *q*, is computed by multiplying *r* by (the significand of) *a*.

Additional adjustment step for the quotient:
[image]

The final rounding is:

```
if a <= (a - q * b/2):
      result = final_biased_exponent | q
else
      result = final_biased_exponent | adjusted_q
```

This works correctly except for two cases: a) the result is subnormal or b) both *a* and *b* are subnormals. 
In those cases, it is not correctly-rounded and the result is off by 1 bit (comparing to x86 results). 
(The numbers *a* and *b* are normalized and the exponent is scaled accordingly when either of *a* or *b* is normalized.)

What can I do to correctly round it for those cases too?

What it seems to me is that the precision is lost at step x5. Since at step x4 the reciprocal is approximated with ~54 bits and it fits 64-bits variable. While in step x5, the reciprocal is approximated by ~108 bits. So at step x5 the full width of the reciprocal does not fit 64 bits. I get the feeling that I do not take this into account properly when I truncate the 128 bits after multiplication to 64 bits.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is Q0.62?

Comment: The case when a & b are both subnormals is easy, because result is then normal. Just scale both operands by 2^precision and proceed. Subnormal result is more involved because you must avoid double rounding...

Comment: For (b): It is standard practice to normalize subnormals prior to the computation; the additional scale factor(s) become part of the exponent computation. From writing multiple floating-point emulations over the years, (b) is a fairly difficult issue when fixed-point arithmetic iteration of the reciprocal is used (as opposed to bitwise or high-radix long-hand division), but I do not recall the details off the top of my head.

Comment: @aka.nice Fixed this.

Comment: @aka.nice The input numbers are normalized if needed and the exponent is scaled. How do avoid double rounding?

Comment: Please see my edited question,  I wrote where it seems to be the inaccuracy arise.

Comment: @Daniel: As I [vaguely] recall, one needs to compute the full 128-bit product and a 128-bit remainder to get the rounding of subnormals right. You could look at existing open-source emulation libraries whether there are better ideas. Make sure to prepare lots of good test vectors ("hard cases") because it is easy for subtle and infrequent rounding errors to creep in (I have painful memories of that).

Comment: Ah OK, Q2.62 refers to a fixed point format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)

Comment: @Daniel how to avoid double rounding? That would be an answer, not just a comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To examine the rounding issue (in round-to-nearest-or-even mode only), I built the emulation code for IEEE-754 `binary32` division from scratch for ease of exposition. Once that was working, I mechanically transformed the code into emulation code for IEEE-754 `binary64` division. The ISO-C99 code for both, including my test frame work, is shown below. The approach differs slightly from asker's algorithm in that it performs intermediate computations in Q1.63 arithmetic for maximum accuracy and uses a table of either 8-bit or 16-bit entries for the starting approximation of the reciprocal.

The rounding step basically subtracts the product of the raw quotient and the divisor from the dividend to form a remainder `rem_raw`. It also forms the remainder `rem_inc` that would result from incrementing the quotient by 1 ulp. By construction, we know that the raw quotient is sufficiently accurate that either it or its incremented value is the correctly rounded result. The remainders can be both positive, both negative, or mixed negative / positive. The remainder smaller in magnitude corresponds to the correctly rounded quotient.

The only difference that exists between rounding normals and subnormals (other than the denormalization step inherent in the latter) is that tie cases cannot occur for normal results, while they can occur for subnormal results. See, for example,

Miloš D. Ercegovac and Tomás Lang, "Digital Arithmetic", Morgan Kaufman, 2004, p. 452

When computing in fixed-point arithmetic, the product of raw quotient and divisor is a double-length product. To compute the remainder precisely without any bits lost, we therefore change the fixed-point representation on the fly to provide additional fraction bits. For that the dividend is left shifted by the appropriate number of bits. But because we know from construction of the algorithm that the preliminary quotient is very close to the true result, we know that during subtraction from the dividend all the high-order bits will cancel. So we only need to compute and subtract the low-order product bits to compute the two remainders.

Because the division of two values each in [1,2) results in a quotient in (0.5, 2), the computation of the quotient may involve a normalization step to get back into the interval [1,2), accompanied by an exponent correction. We need to account for this when lining up the dividend and the product of quotient and divisor for subtraction, see `normalization_shift` in the code below.

Since the code below is of an exploratory nature, it was not written with extreme optimization in mind. Various tweaks are possible, as are replacements of portable code with platform-specific intrinsics or inline assembly. Likewise, the basic test framework below could be strengthened by incorporating various techniques for generating hard-to-round cases from the literature. For example, I have used division test vectors accompanying the following paper in the past:

Brigitte Verdonk, Annie Cuyt, and Dennis Verschaeren. "A precision- and range-independent tool for testing floating-point arithmetic I: basic operations, square root, and remainder." *ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software*, Vol. 27, No. 1, March 2001, pp. 92-118.

The pattern-based test vectors of my test framework were motivated by the following publication:

N. L. Schryer, "A Test of a Computer's Floating-Point Unit." Computer Science Technical Report no. 89, AT&T Bell Laboratories, Murray Hill, N.J. (1981).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define TEST_FP32_DIV     (0) /* 0: binary64 division; 1: binary32 division */
#define PURELY_RANDOM     (1)
#define PATTERN_BASED     (2)
#define TEST_MODE         (PATTERN_BASED)
#define ITO_TAKAGI_YAJIMA (1) /* more accurate recip. starting approximation */

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a)
{
    uint32_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

float uint32_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

uint32_t umul32hi (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    return (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)a*b) >> 32);
}

int clz32 (uint32_t a)
{
    uint32_t r = 32;
    if (a >= 0x00010000) { a >>= 16; r -= 16; }
    if (a >= 0x00000100) { a >>=  8; r -=  8; }
    if (a >= 0x00000010) { a >>=  4; r -=  4; }
    if (a >= 0x00000004) { a >>=  2; r -=  2; }
    r -= a - (a & (a >> 1));
    return r;
}

#if ITO_TAKAGI_YAJIMA
/* Masayuki Ito, Naofumi Takagi, Shuzo Yajima, "Efficient Initial Approximation
   for Multiplicative Division and Square Root by a Multiplication with Operand
   Modification". IEEE Transactions on Computers, Vol. 46, No. 4, April 1997,
   pp. 495-498.
*/
#define LOG2_TAB_ENTRIES (6)
#define TAB_ENTRIES      (1 << LOG2_TAB_ENTRIES)
#define TAB_ENTRY_BITS   (16)
/* approx. err. ~= 5.146e-5 */
const uint16_t b1tab [64] =
{
    0xfc0f, 0xf46b, 0xed20, 0xe626, 0xdf7a, 0xd918, 0xd2fa, 0xcd1e,
    0xc77f, 0xc21b, 0xbcee, 0xb7f5, 0xb32e, 0xae96, 0xaa2a, 0xa5e9,
    0xa1d1, 0x9dde, 0x9a11, 0x9665, 0x92dc, 0x8f71, 0x8c25, 0x88f6,
    0x85e2, 0x82e8, 0x8008, 0x7d3f, 0x7a8e, 0x77f2, 0x756c, 0x72f9,
    0x709b, 0x6e4e, 0x6c14, 0x69eb, 0x67d2, 0x65c8, 0x63cf, 0x61e3,
    0x6006, 0x5e36, 0x5c73, 0x5abd, 0x5913, 0x5774, 0x55e1, 0x5458,
    0x52da, 0x5166, 0x4ffc, 0x4e9b, 0x4d43, 0x4bf3, 0x4aad, 0x496e,
    0x4837, 0x4708, 0x45e0, 0x44c0, 0x43a6, 0x4293, 0x4187, 0x4081
};
#else // ITO_TAKAGI_YAJIMA
#define LOG2_TAB_ENTRIES (7)
#define TAB_ENTRIES      (1 << LOG2_TAB_ENTRIES)
#define TAB_ENTRY_BITS   (8)
/* approx. err. ~= 5.585e-3 */
const uint8_t rcp_tab [TAB_ENTRIES] =
{
    0xff, 0xfd, 0xfb, 0xf9, 0xf7, 0xf5, 0xf4, 0xf2,
    0xf0, 0xee, 0xed, 0xeb, 0xe9, 0xe8, 0xe6, 0xe4,
    0xe3, 0xe1, 0xe0, 0xde, 0xdd, 0xdb, 0xda, 0xd8,
    0xd7, 0xd5, 0xd4, 0xd3, 0xd1, 0xd0, 0xcf, 0xcd,
    0xcc, 0xcb, 0xca, 0xc8, 0xc7, 0xc6, 0xc5, 0xc4,
    0xc2, 0xc1, 0xc0, 0xbf, 0xbe, 0xbd, 0xbc, 0xbb,
    0xba, 0xb9, 0xb8, 0xb7, 0xb6, 0xb5, 0xb4, 0xb3,
    0xb2, 0xb1, 0xb0, 0xaf, 0xae, 0xad, 0xac, 0xab,
    0xaa, 0xa9, 0xa8, 0xa8, 0xa7, 0xa6, 0xa5, 0xa4,
    0xa3, 0xa3, 0xa2, 0xa1, 0xa0, 0x9f, 0x9f, 0x9e,
    0x9d, 0x9c, 0x9c, 0x9b, 0x9a, 0x99, 0x99, 0x98,
    0x97, 0x97, 0x96, 0x95, 0x95, 0x94, 0x93, 0x93,
    0x92, 0x91, 0x91, 0x90, 0x8f, 0x8f, 0x8e, 0x8e,
    0x8d, 0x8c, 0x8c, 0x8b, 0x8b, 0x8a, 0x89, 0x89,
    0x88, 0x88, 0x87, 0x87, 0x86, 0x85, 0x85, 0x84,
    0x84, 0x83, 0x83, 0x82, 0x82, 0x81, 0x81, 0x80
};
#endif // ITO_TAKAGI_YAJIMA

#define FP32_MANT_BITS       (23)
#define FP32_EXPO_BITS       (8)
#define FP32_SIGN_MASK       (0x80000000u)
#define FP32_MANT_MASK       (0x007fffffu)
#define FP32_EXPO_MASK       (0x7f800000u)
#define FP32_MAX_EXPO        (0xff)
#define FP32_EXPO_BIAS       (127)
#define FP32_INFTY           (0x7f800000u)
#define FP32_QNAN_BIT        (0x00400000u)
#define FP32_QNAN_INDEFINITE (0xffc00000u)
#define FP32_MANT_INT_BIT    (0x00800000u)

uint32_t fp32_div_core (uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    uint32_t expo_x, expo_y, expo_r, sign_r;
    uint32_t abs_x, abs_y, f, l, p, r, z, s;
    int x_is_zero, y_is_zero, normalization_shift;

    expo_x = (x & FP32_EXPO_MASK) >> FP32_MANT_BITS;
    expo_y = (y & FP32_EXPO_MASK) >> FP32_MANT_BITS;
    sign_r = (x ^ y) & FP32_SIGN_MASK;

    abs_x = x & ~FP32_SIGN_MASK;
    abs_y = y & ~FP32_SIGN_MASK;
    x_is_zero = (abs_x == 0);
    y_is_zero = (abs_y == 0);

    if ((expo_x == FP32_MAX_EXPO) || (expo_y == FP32_MAX_EXPO) || 
        x_is_zero || y_is_zero) {
        int x_is_nan = (abs_x >  FP32_INFTY);
        int x_is_inf = (abs_x == FP32_INFTY);
        int y_is_nan = (abs_y >  FP32_INFTY);
        int y_is_inf = (abs_y == FP32_INFTY);
        if (x_is_nan) {
            r = x | FP32_QNAN_BIT;
        } else if (y_is_nan) {
            r = y | FP32_QNAN_BIT;
        } else if ((x_is_zero && y_is_zero) || (x_is_inf && y_is_inf)) {
            r = FP32_QNAN_INDEFINITE;
        } else if (x_is_zero || y_is_inf) {
            r = sign_r;
        } else if (y_is_zero || x_is_inf) {
            r = sign_r | FP32_INFTY;
        }
    } else {
        /* normalize any subnormals */
        if (expo_x == 0) {
            s = clz32 (abs_x) - FP32_EXPO_BITS;
            x = x << s;
            expo_x = expo_x - (s - 1);
        }
        if (expo_y == 0) {
            s = clz32 (abs_y) - FP32_EXPO_BITS;
            y = y << s;
            expo_y = expo_y - (s - 1);
        }
        //
        expo_r = expo_x - expo_y + FP32_EXPO_BIAS;
        /* extract mantissas */
        x = x & FP32_MANT_MASK;
        y = y & FP32_MANT_MASK;
#if ITO_TAKAGI_YAJIMA
        /* initial approx based on 6 most significant stored mantissa bits */
        r = b1tab [y >> (FP32_MANT_BITS - LOG2_TAB_ENTRIES)];
        /* make implicit integer bit of mantissa explicit */
        x = x | FP32_MANT_INT_BIT;
        y = y | FP32_MANT_INT_BIT;
        r = r * ((y ^ ((1u << (FP32_MANT_BITS - LOG2_TAB_ENTRIES)) - 1)) >> 
                 (FP32_MANT_BITS + 1 + TAB_ENTRY_BITS - 32));
        /* pre-scale y for more efficient fixed-point computation */
        z = y << FP32_EXPO_BITS;
#else // ITO_TAKAGI_YAJIMA
        /* initial approx based on 7 most significant stored mantissa bits */
        r = rcp_tab [y >> (FP32_MANT_BITS - LOG2_TAB_ENTRIES)];
        /* make implicit integer bit of mantissa explicit */
        x = x | FP32_MANT_INT_BIT;
        y = y | FP32_MANT_INT_BIT;
        /* pre-scale y for more efficient fixed-point computation */
        z = y << FP32_EXPO_BITS;
        /* first NR iteration r1 = 2*r0-y*r0*r0 */
        f = r * r;
        p = umul32hi (z, f << (32 - 2 * TAB_ENTRY_BITS));
        r = (r << (32 - TAB_ENTRY_BITS)) - p;
#endif // ITO_TAKAGI_YAJIMA
        /* second NR iteration: r2 = r1*(2-y*r1) */
        p = umul32hi (z, r << 1);
        f = 0u - p;
        r = umul32hi (f, r << 1);
        /* compute quotient as wide product x*(1/y) = x*r */
        l = x * (r << 1);
        r = umul32hi (x, r << 1);
        /* normalize mantissa to be in [1,2) */
        normalization_shift = (r & FP32_MANT_INT_BIT) == 0;
        expo_r -= normalization_shift;
        r = (r << normalization_shift) | ((l >> 1) >> (32 - 1 - normalization_shift));
        if ((expo_r > 0) && (expo_r < FP32_MAX_EXPO)) { /* result is normal */
            int32_t rem_raw, rem_inc, inc;
            /* align x with product y*quotient */
            x = x << (FP32_MANT_BITS + normalization_shift + 1);
            /* compute product y*quotient */
            y = y << 1;
            p = y * r;
            /* compute x - y*quotient, for both raw and incremented quotient */
            rem_raw = x - p;
            rem_inc = rem_raw - y;
            /* round to nearest: tie case _cannot_ occur */
            inc = abs (rem_inc) < abs (rem_raw);
            /* build final results from sign, exponent, mantissa */
            r = sign_r | (((expo_r - 1) << FP32_MANT_BITS) + r + inc);
        } else if ((int)expo_r >= FP32_MAX_EXPO) { /* result overflowed */
            r = sign_r | FP32_INFTY;
        } else { /* result underflowed */
            int denorm_shift = 1 - expo_r;
            if (denorm_shift > (FP32_MANT_BITS + 1)) { /* massive underflow */
                r = sign_r;
            } else {
                int32_t rem_raw, rem_inc, inc;
                /* denormalize quotient */
                r = r >> denorm_shift;
                /* align x with product y*quotient */ 
                x = x << (FP32_MANT_BITS + normalization_shift + 1 - denorm_shift);
                /* compute product y*quotient */
                y = y << 1;
                p = y * r;
                /* compute x - y*quotient, for both raw & incremented quotient*/
                rem_raw = x - p;
                rem_inc = rem_raw - y;
                /* round to nearest or even: tie case _can_ occur */
                inc = ((abs (rem_inc) < abs (rem_raw)) ||
                       (abs (rem_inc) == abs (rem_raw) && (r & 1)));
                /* build final result from sign and mantissa */
                r = sign_r | (r + inc);
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
}

float fp32_div (float a, float b)
{
    uint32_t x, y, r;
    x = float_as_uint32 (a);
    y = float_as_uint32 (b);
    r = fp32_div_core (x, y);
    return uint32_as_float (r);
}

uint64_t double_as_uint64 (double a)
{
    uint64_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

double uint64_as_double (uint64_t a)
{
    double r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

uint64_t umul64hi (uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    uint64_t a_lo = (uint64_t)(uint32_t)a;
    uint64_t a_hi = a >> 32;
    uint64_t b_lo = (uint64_t)(uint32_t)b;
    uint64_t b_hi = b >> 32;
    uint64_t p0 = a_lo * b_lo;
    uint64_t p1 = a_lo * b_hi;
    uint64_t p2 = a_hi * b_lo;
    uint64_t p3 = a_hi * b_hi;
    uint32_t cy = (uint32_t)(((p0 >> 32) + (uint32_t)p1 + (uint32_t)p2) >> 32);
    return p3 + (p1 >> 32) + (p2 >> 32) + cy;
}

int clz64 (uint64_t a)
{
    uint64_t r = 64;
    if (a >= 0x100000000ULL) { a >>= 32; r -= 32; }
    if (a >= 0x000010000ULL) { a >>= 16; r -= 16; }
    if (a >= 0x000000100ULL) { a >>=  8; r -=  8; }
    if (a >= 0x000000010ULL) { a >>=  4; r -=  4; }
    if (a >= 0x000000004ULL) { a >>=  2; r -=  2; }
    r -= a - (a & (a >> 1));
    return r;
}


#define FP64_MANT_BITS       (52)
#define FP64_EXPO_BITS       (11)
#define FP64_EXPO_MASK       (0x7ff0000000000000ULL)
#define FP64_SIGN_MASK       (0x8000000000000000ULL)
#define FP64_MANT_MASK       (0x000fffffffffffffULL)
#define FP64_MAX_EXPO        (0x7ff)
#define FP64_EXPO_BIAS       (1023)
#define FP64_INFTY           (0x7ff0000000000000ULL)
#define FP64_QNAN_BIT        (0x0008000000000000ULL)
#define FP64_QNAN_INDEFINITE (0xfff8000000000000ULL)
#define FP64_MANT_INT_BIT    (0x0010000000000000ULL)

uint64_t fp64_div_core (uint64_t x, uint64_t y)
{
    uint64_t expo_x, expo_y, expo_r, sign_r;
    uint64_t abs_x, abs_y, f, l, p, r, z, s;
    int x_is_zero, y_is_zero, normalization_shift;

    expo_x = (x & FP64_EXPO_MASK) >> FP64_MANT_BITS;
    expo_y = (y & FP64_EXPO_MASK) >> FP64_MANT_BITS;
    sign_r = (x ^ y) & FP64_SIGN_MASK;

    abs_x = x & ~FP64_SIGN_MASK;
    abs_y = y & ~FP64_SIGN_MASK;
    x_is_zero = (abs_x == 0);
    y_is_zero = (abs_y == 0);

    if ((expo_x == FP64_MAX_EXPO) || (expo_y == FP64_MAX_EXPO) || 
        x_is_zero || y_is_zero) {
        int x_is_nan = (abs_x >  FP64_INFTY);
        int x_is_inf = (abs_x == FP64_INFTY);
        int y_is_nan = (abs_y >  FP64_INFTY);
        int y_is_inf = (abs_y == FP64_INFTY);
        if (x_is_nan) {
            r = x | FP64_QNAN_BIT;
        } else if (y_is_nan) {
            r = y | FP64_QNAN_BIT;
        } else if ((x_is_zero && y_is_zero) || (x_is_inf && y_is_inf)) {
            r = FP64_QNAN_INDEFINITE;
        } else if (x_is_zero || y_is_inf) {
            r = sign_r;
        } else if (y_is_zero || x_is_inf) {
            r = sign_r | FP64_INFTY;
        }
    } else {
        /* normalize any subnormals */
        if (expo_x == 0) {
            s = clz64 (abs_x) - FP64_EXPO_BITS;
            x = x << s;
            expo_x = expo_x - (s - 1);
        }
        if (expo_y == 0) {
            s = clz64 (abs_y) - FP64_EXPO_BITS;
            y = y << s;
            expo_y = expo_y - (s - 1);
        }
        //
        expo_r = expo_x - expo_y + FP64_EXPO_BIAS;
        /* extract mantissas */
        x = x & FP64_MANT_MASK;
        y = y & FP64_MANT_MASK;
#if ITO_TAKAGI_YAJIMA
        /* initial approx based on 6 most significant stored mantissa bits */
        r = b1tab [y >> (FP64_MANT_BITS - LOG2_TAB_ENTRIES)];
        /* make implicit integer bit of mantissa explicit */
        x = x | FP64_MANT_INT_BIT;
        y = y | FP64_MANT_INT_BIT;
        r = r * ((y ^ ((1ULL << (FP64_MANT_BITS - LOG2_TAB_ENTRIES)) - 1)) >> 
                 (FP64_MANT_BITS + 1 + TAB_ENTRY_BITS - 64));
        /* pre-scale y for more efficient fixed-point computation */
        z = y << FP64_EXPO_BITS;
#else // ITO_TAKAGI_YAJIMA
        /* initial approx based on 7 most significant stored mantissa bits */
        r = rcp_tab [y >> (FP64_MANT_BITS - LOG2_TAB_ENTRIES)];
        /* make implicit integer bit of mantissa explicit */
        x = x | FP64_MANT_INT_BIT;
        y = y | FP64_MANT_INT_BIT;
        /* pre-scale y for more efficient fixed-point computation */
        z = y << FP64_EXPO_BITS;
        /* first NR iteration r1 = 2*r0-y*r0*r0 */
        f = r * r;
        p = umul64hi (z, f << (64 - 2 * TAB_ENTRY_BITS));
        r = (r << (64 - TAB_ENTRY_BITS)) - p;
#endif // ITO_TAKAGI_YAJIMA
        /* second NR iteration: r2 = r1*(2-y*r1) */
        p = umul64hi (z, r << 1);
        f = 0u - p;
        r = umul64hi (f, r << 1);
        /* third NR iteration: r3 = r2*(2-y*r2) */
        p = umul64hi (z, r << 1);
        f = 0u - p;
        r = umul64hi (f, r << 1);
        /* compute quotient as wide product x*(1/y) = x*r */
        l = x * (r << 1);
        r = umul64hi (x, r << 1);
        /* normalize mantissa to be in [1,2) */
        normalization_shift = (r & FP64_MANT_INT_BIT) == 0;
        expo_r -= normalization_shift;
        r = (r << normalization_shift) | ((l >> 1) >> (64 - 1 - normalization_shift));
        if ((expo_r > 0) && (expo_r < FP64_MAX_EXPO)) { /* result is normal */
            int64_t rem_raw, rem_inc;
            int inc;
            /* align x with product y*quotient */
            x = x << (FP64_MANT_BITS + 1 + normalization_shift);
            /* compute product y*quotient */
            y = y << 1;
            p = y * r;
            /* compute x - y*quotient, for both raw and incremented quotient */
            rem_raw = x - p;
            rem_inc = rem_raw - y;
            /* round to nearest: tie case _cannot_ occur */
            inc = llabs (rem_inc) < llabs (rem_raw);
            /* build final results from sign, exponent, mantissa */
            r = sign_r | (((expo_r - 1) << FP64_MANT_BITS) + r + inc);
        } else if ((int)expo_r >= FP64_MAX_EXPO) { /* result overflowed */
            r = sign_r | FP64_INFTY;
        } else { /* result underflowed */
            int denorm_shift = 1 - expo_r;
            if (denorm_shift > (FP64_MANT_BITS + 1)) { /* massive underflow */
                r = sign_r;
            } else {
                int64_t rem_raw, rem_inc;
                int inc;
                /* denormalize quotient */
                r = r >> denorm_shift;
                /* align x with product y*quotient */ 
                x = x << (FP64_MANT_BITS + 1 + normalization_shift - denorm_shift);
                /* compute product y*quotient */
                y = y << 1;
                p = y * r;
                /* compute x - y*quotient, for both raw & incremented quotient*/
                rem_raw = x - p;
                rem_inc = rem_raw - y;
                /* round to nearest or even: tie case _can_ occur */
                inc = ((llabs (rem_inc) < llabs (rem_raw)) ||
                       (llabs (rem_inc) == llabs (rem_raw) && (r & 1)));
                /* build final result from sign and mantissa */
                r = sign_r | (r + inc);
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
}

double fp64_div (double a, double b)
{
    uint64_t x, y, r;
    x = double_as_uint64 (a);
    y = double_as_uint64 (b);
    r = fp64_div_core (x, y);
    return uint64_as_double (r);
}

#if TEST_FP32_DIV

// Fixes via: Greg Rose, KISS: A Bit Too Simple. http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007
static uint32_t kiss_z=362436069,kiss_w=521288629, kiss_jsr=362436069,kiss_jcong=123456789;
#define znew (kiss_z=36969*(kiss_z&0xffff)+(kiss_z>>16))
#define wnew (kiss_w=18000*(kiss_w&0xffff)+(kiss_w>>16))
#define MWC  ((znew<<16)+wnew)
#define SHR3 (kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr<<13),kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr>>17),kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr<<5))
#define CONG (kiss_jcong=69069*kiss_jcong+13579)
#define KISS ((MWC^CONG)+SHR3)

uint32_t v[8192];

int main (void)
{
    uint64_t count = 0;
    float a, b, res, ref;
    uint32_t ires, iref, diff;
    uint32_t i, j, patterns, idx = 0, nbrBits = sizeof (v[0]) * CHAR_BIT;

    printf ("testing fp32 division\n");

    /* pattern class 1: 2**i */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        v [idx] = ((uint32_t)1 << i);
        idx++;
    }
    /* pattern class 2: 2**i-1 */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        v [idx] = (((uint32_t)1 << i) - 1);
        idx++;
    }
    /* pattern class 3: 2**i+1 */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        v [idx] = (((uint32_t)1 << i) + 1);
        idx++;
    }
    /* pattern class 4: 2**i + 2**j */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nbrBits; j++) {
            v [idx] = (((uint32_t)1 << i) + ((uint32_t)1 << j));
            idx++;
        }
    }
    /* pattern class 5: 2**i - 2**j */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nbrBits; j++) {
            v [idx] = (((uint32_t)1 << i) - ((uint32_t)1 << j));
            idx++;
        }
    }
    /* pattern class 6: MAX_UINT/(2**i+1) rep. blocks of i zeros an i ones */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        v [idx] = ((~(uint32_t)0) / (((uint32_t)1 << i) + 1));
        idx++;
    }
    patterns = idx;
    /* pattern class 6: one's complement of pattern classes 1 through 5 */
    for (i = 0; i < patterns; i++) {
        v [idx] = ~v [i];
        idx++;
    }
    /* pattern class 7: two's complement of pattern classes 1 through 5 */
    for (i = 0; i < patterns; i++) {
        v [idx] = ~v [i] + 1;
        idx++;
    }
    patterns = idx;

#if ITO_TAKAGI_YAJIMA
    printf ("initial reciprocal based on method of Ito, Takagi, and Yajima\n");
#else
    printf ("initial reciprocal based on straight 8-bit table\n");
#endif
#if TEST_MODE == PURELY_RANDOM
    printf ("using purely random test vectors\n");
#elif TEST_MODE == PATTERN_BASED
    printf ("using pattern-based test vectors\n");
    printf ("#patterns = %u\n", patterns);
#endif // TEST_MODE

    do {
#if TEST_MODE == PURELY_RANDOM
        a = uint32_as_float (KISS);
        b = uint32_as_float (KISS);
#elif TEST_MODE == PATTERN_BASED
        a = uint32_as_float ((v [KISS % patterns] & FP32_MANT_MASK) | (KISS & ~FP32_MANT_MASK));
        b = uint32_as_float ((v [KISS % patterns] & FP32_MANT_MASK) | (KISS & ~FP32_MANT_MASK));
#endif // TEST_MODE
        ref = a / b;
        res = fp32_div (a, b);
        ires = float_as_uint32 (res);
        iref = float_as_uint32 (ref);

        diff = (ires > iref) ? (ires - iref) : (iref - ires);
        if (diff) {
            printf ("a=% 15.6a  b=% 15.6a  res=% 15.6a  ref=% 15.6a\n", a, b, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        count++;
        if ((count & 0xffffff) == 0) {
            printf ("\r%llu", count);
        }
    } while (1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#else /* TEST_FP32_DIV */

/*
  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c/qFv18ql_WlU/IK8KGZZFJx4J
*/
static uint64_t kiss64_x = 1234567890987654321ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_c = 123456123456123456ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_y = 362436362436362436ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_z = 1066149217761810ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_t;

#define MWC64  (kiss64_t = (kiss64_x << 58) + kiss64_c, \
                kiss64_c = (kiss64_x >> 6), kiss64_x += kiss64_t, \
                kiss64_c += (kiss64_x < kiss64_t), kiss64_x)
#define XSH64  (kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 13), kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y >> 17), \
                kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 43))
#define CNG64  (kiss64_z = 6906969069ULL * kiss64_z + 1234567ULL)
#define KISS64 (MWC64 + XSH64 + CNG64)

uint64_t v[32768];

int main (void)
{
    uint64_t ires, iref, diff, count = 0;
    double a, b, res, ref;
    uint32_t i, j, patterns, idx = 0, nbrBits = sizeof (v[0]) * CHAR_BIT;

    printf ("testing fp64 division\n");

    /* pattern class 1: 2**i */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        v [idx] = ((uint64_t)1 << i);
        idx++;
    }
    /* pattern class 2: 2**i-1 */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        v [idx] = (((uint64_t)1 << i) - 1);
        idx++;
    }
    /* pattern class 3: 2**i+1 */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        v [idx] = (((uint64_t)1 << i) + 1);
        idx++;
    }
    /* pattern class 4: 2**i + 2**j */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nbrBits; j++) {
            v [idx] = (((uint64_t)1 << i) + ((uint64_t)1 << j));
            idx++;
        }
    }
    /* pattern class 5: 2**i - 2**j */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nbrBits; j++) {
            v [idx] = (((uint64_t)1 << i) - ((uint64_t)1 << j));
            idx++;
        }
    }
    /* pattern class 6: MAX_UINT/(2**i+1) rep. blocks of i zeros an i ones */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        v [idx] = ((~(uint64_t)0) / (((uint64_t)1 << i) + 1));
        idx++;
    }
    patterns = idx;
    /* pattern class 6: one's complement of pattern classes 1 through 5 */
    for (i = 0; i < patterns; i++) {
        v [idx] = ~v [i];
        idx++;
    }
    /* pattern class 7: two's complement of pattern classes 1 through 5 */
    for (i = 0; i < patterns; i++) {
        v [idx] = ~v [i] + 1;
        idx++;
    }
    patterns = idx;

#if ITO_TAKAGI_YAJIMA
    printf ("initial reciprocal based on method of Ito, Takagi, and Yajima\n");
#else
    printf ("initial reciprocal based on straight 8-bit table\n");
#endif
#if TEST_MODE == PURELY_RANDOM
    printf ("using purely random test vectors\n");
#elif TEST_MODE == PATTERN_BASED
    printf ("using pattern-based test vectors\n");
    printf ("#patterns = %u\n", patterns);
#endif // TEST_MODE

    do {
#if TEST_MODE == PURELY_RANDOM
        a = uint64_as_double (KISS64);
        b = uint64_as_double (KISS64);
#elif TEST_MODE == PATTERN_BASED
        a = uint64_as_double ((v [KISS64 % patterns] & FP64_MANT_MASK) | (KISS64 & ~FP64_MANT_MASK));
        b = uint64_as_double ((v [KISS64 % patterns] & FP64_MANT_MASK) | (KISS64 & ~FP64_MANT_MASK));
#endif // TEST_MODE

        ref = a / b;
        res = fp64_div (a, b);
        ires = double_as_uint64(res);
        iref = double_as_uint64(ref);

        diff = (ires > iref) ? (ires - iref) : (iref - ires);
        if (diff) {
            printf ("a=% 23.13a  b=% 23.13a  res=% 23.13a  ref=% 23.13a\n", a, b, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        count++;
        if ((count & 0xffffff) == 0) {
            printf ("\r%llu", count);
        }
    } while (1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
#endif /* TEST_FP32_DIV */
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! This is very educational. I have learned from this exactly where were the sources of inaccuracy in what I have implemented. Also, thank you for the testing framework which is also very educational on ways for testing floating-point implementations.

Comment: With regard to the remainder computation. The lower bits of the product are aligned against the lower bits of the dividents' significand and then subtracted, right? But how come they are of the same order? The lower bits of the product are below 2^-53 magnitude while the lower bits of the significand are of 2^-53 magnitude.

Comment: @Daniel Correct. That is the reason why the dividend is shifted left prior to the subtraction. Basically what is happening in this step is an on-the-fly conversion to a different fixed-point format with more fraction bits so we preserve *all* low order bits that we need to compute the remainder *without error*. Algorithmically, we know that dividend and product of quotient times divisor are of the same magnitude, by construction.

Comment: Take a look at post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68602043/what-are-the-details-of-the-juniper-floating-point-scenario-bug-wherein-the-stic, where I worked out the details of rounding, including an implementation that does it incorrectly, albeit with no real impact.