# some question about "correctly-rounded double-precision division"

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

With  [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58722891/780717) about "correctly-rounded double-precision division", I have no idea Under this condition of "result is normal" , why do we need to do these operations? 1. y = y<<1 ; and 2. rem_inc = rem_raw - y;
PS.I am new at SO, why I can't add a comment under [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58722891/780717)

Comment: Fushiyu1 "why I can't add a comment" --> You can post [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) when reputation reaches 50.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica Thanks for your reply. And I will try it. Maybe the process of waiting for the reputation to reach 50 is a bit long, so I will put the question here first