# What are the details of the Juniper floating-point scenario/bug wherein the sticky bit is lost?

Tags: networking, floating-point, floating-accuracy

On some Juniper MX routers, floats are not handled correctly:  The sticky bit is lost if it is shifted more that 8 bits to the right (underflow) during a calculation.  Is there a workaround for this?  Are there any known impacts?  Has it been fixed?  Is this an IEEE acceptable option?  Does the issue exist in other systems?

Example with Math Details (best viewed with fixed width font, and wide screen):

```
                                                                                                                                                                          1
shifts:                                                                                                                                                          12345678901
 4095.05615204245304994401521980762481689453125000000000   = 0x1.ffe1cbff5e3e1p+11 = 0x40affe1cbff5e3e1 =  111111111111.00001110010111111111101011110001111100001
+   1.0000137123424794882708965815254487097263336181640625 = 0x1.0000e60e10001p+0  = 0x3ff0000170168000 =             1.0000000000000000111001100000111000010000000000000001
                                                                                                                                                                           ^
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                          1000000000000.000011100110000011100001000000000000000010s
                                                                                                                                                               LGRS
                                                                                                                                                               0101 
                                                                                                                   1          2         3         4         5       
mantissa bit #:                                                                                           1234567890123 4567890123456789012345678901234567890123    
 4096.0561657547959839575923979282379150390625             = 0x1.0000e60e10001p+12 = 0x40b0000e60e10001 = 1000000000000.0000111001100000111000010000000000000001               (on "all" systems/correct)
 4096.056165754795074462890625                             = 0x1.0000e60e10000p+12 = 0x40b0000e60e10000 = 1000000000000.0000111001100000111000010000000000000000               (on Juniper router)
                   ^                                                         ^                        ^                                                        ^
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Juniper MX routers and do not know if I can help, but you should  clarify your question. I suggest using tables to present the data, and maybe the `<pre>` tag within table cells to use a fixed-width text. Formatting help is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Then make it clear how the data shows the sticky bit is lost.

Comment: The data you show is a single addition with a result that is not correctly rounded to the nearest representable value. There is no sticky bit visible in it. A sticky bit is an internal implementation detail; it would be visible in the hardware design. Your statement that it is lost if “it is shifted more that 8 bits to the right” suggests you have done more experiments regarding this. So some additions round up, some round down, but those where ULP and the trailing fraction at the ULP boundary is 0.1000000…1 round down even though they should round up? That should be in the question.

Comment: What does the manufacturer documentation say about floating-point? Does it assert that IEEE-754 floating-point is used? What language are you programming it in?

Comment: There is no rounding behavior specified by IEEE-754 that would round 0.100000000001 down but round 0.11 up. If the Juniper MX is doing this, it is not rounding according to any IEEE-754 specification.

Comment: @Andrew The observed behavior is entirely consistent with the use of an x87 FPU whose precision control is set to extended precision. I confirmed by running your test case with this setting. Such an x87 setting was used by many 32-bit flavors of Unix-like operating systems running on x86 hardware, for example. This gives rise to double rounding issues. In this case: The result of the addition is first rounded to extended precision and stored into a x87 register. When the result is stored from the extended-precision register to a double precision memory operand, a second rounding occurs.

Answer (score 3):

[Internet source](https://www.niap-ccevs.org/Product/Compliant.cfm?PID=11012) informs me that a number of MX-series routers utilize Intel x86 CPUs. The observed behavior is entirely consistent with the use of an x87 FPU for floating-point computation (as opposed to SSE or AVX), when that x87 is configured to operate in extended-precision mode.

The x87 FPU stores all operands in 80-bit registers, where each register holds a floating-point operand using 64 significand (mantissa) bits, and the integer bit of the significand is explicit. Bits 8 and 9 of the FPU control word represent the *precision control* field that indicate at which bit position the FPU will round results. A setting of 2 is equivalent to double precision while a setting of 3 means round to extended precision.

Most Unix-like 32-bit operating systems set the x87 rounding control to 3, while Windows set it to 2. I do not know whether modern Junos is a 32-bit or 64-bit OS. It may retain use of the x87 and FPU precision control setting of 3 for reasons of backwards compatibility.

With x87 precision control set to 3 (extended precision) there is a issue with *double rounding*. Results of floating-point operations are first rounded to extended precision and stored in an internal FPU register. Later, the data is taken from the register and rounded *again* when this result is stored out to a memory location corresponding to a `double` variable.

I programmed up the specific scenario from the question on Windows64 using the Intel compiler for easy access to x87 assembly language instructions. The program dumps the two source operands `a` and `b` and the sum `r` in three different formats (decimal floating point, hexadecimal floating point, and binary) and also dumps the internal 80-bit representation of these operands (with a `t` prefix).

By defining `USE_X87_EXTENDED_PRECISION` as either `0` or `1` the precision control of the FPU can be set to either double precision or extended precision prior to the computation, and the value of the relevant FPU control word is shown as `compute cw`. With `USE_X87_EXTENDED_PRECISION` set to `0`, the output of the program is:

```
original cw=027f
compute  cw=027f
a=4.0950561520424530e+003  0x1.ffe1cbff5e3e1p+11 40affe1cbff5e3e1 ta=400afff0e5ffaf1f0800
b=1.0000137123424795e+000   0x1.0000e60e10001p+0 3ff0000e60e10001 tb=3fff8000730708000800
r=4.0960561657547960e+003  0x1.0000e60e10001p+12 40b0000e60e10001 tr=400b8000730708000800
```

However, when `USE_X87_EXTENDED_PRECISION` is `1`, the result is:

```
original cw=027f
compute  cw=037f
a=4.0950561520424530e+003 0x1.ffe1cbff5e3e1p+11 40affe1cbff5e3e1 ta=400afff0e5ffaf1f0800
b=1.0000137123424795e+000  0x1.0000e60e10001p+0 3ff0000e60e10001 tb=3fff8000730708000800
r=4.0960561657547951e+003 0x1.0000e60e10000p+12 40b0000e60e10000 tr=400b8000730708000400
```

During the second rounding, from `tr` to `r`, the round bit is 1, but the sticky bit is 0 as all trailing significand bits past the round bit are zero, so the "even" part of the default rounding mode "round to nearest or even" kicks in.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define USE_X87_EXTENDED_PRECISION (1)

typedef struct tbyte {
    uint64_t l;
    uint16_t h;
} tbyte;

uint64_t double_as_uint64 (double a)
{
    uint64_t r; memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r); return r;
}

int main (void)
{
    double a = 0x1.ffe1cbff5e3e1p+11;
    double b = 0x1.0000e60e10001p+0;
    double r;
    uint16_t cw_orig, cw_comp, cw_temp;
    tbyte ta, tb, tr;

    __asm fstcw word ptr [cw_orig];
#if USE_X87_EXTENDED_PRECISION
    cw_temp = cw_orig | (3 << 8);
    __asm fldcw word ptr [cw_temp];
#endif // USE_X87_EXTENDED_PRECISION
    __asm fstcw word ptr [cw_comp];
    __asm fld qword ptr [a];
    __asm fld qword ptr [b];
    __asm fld st(1);
    __asm fadd st, st(1);
    __asm fst qword ptr [r];
    __asm fstp tbyte ptr [tr];
    __asm fstp tbyte ptr [tb];
    __asm fstp tbyte ptr [ta];
    __asm fldcw word ptr [cw_orig];

    printf ("original cw=%04x\n", cw_orig);
    printf ("compute  cw=%04x\n", cw_comp);
    printf ("a=%23.16e %21.13a %016llx ta=%04x%016llx\n", a, a, double_as_uint64 (a), ta.h, ta.l);
    printf ("b=%23.16e %21.13a %016llx tb=%04x%016llx\n", b, b, double_as_uint64 (b), tb.h, tb.l);
    printf ("r=%23.16e %21.13a %016llx tr=%04x%016llx\n", r, r, double_as_uint64 (r), tr.h, tr.l);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @Andrew I think the 8-bit shift is a red herring, possibly suggested by a limited number of observations. You may want to re-examine the failing cases under a double-rounding hypothesis.