# Floating point: Can I skip the sticky bit if I am only rounding ties to away?

Tags: floating-point

I'm writing floating-point functions for a very limited 8-bit processor. When I shift the significand right in order to align the binary points for an add or subtract, I shift the bits that fall off the right side of the significand field into a rounding byte. If I'm only implementing the "round ties to away" rounding method, do I need to maintain a sticky bit, or really pay attention to anything but the most significant bit of the rounding byte? I think that with this rounding method, if the MSB is 1, I round away from zero (up for positive numbers), otherwise toward zero.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. For ties-to-away, you can simply add `0x80` to the rounding byte and propagate the carry, 
or increment the significand by 1 ulp if rounding byte is greater or equal to `0x80`. Since ties-to-away provides 
biased rounding, you may want to rethink the design decision. Maintaining the sticky information in the low-order 
seven bits of the rounding byte doesn't cost many instructions, and the conditional incrementing is only marginally 
more involved (OR the significand lsb into the sticky, then compare whether `> 0x80`).

Comment: Here are three ways to efficiently round to nearest ties-to-even (using a rounding word, but same idea as using a rounding byte). Which is best depends on platform: 
[1] `r = (expo_a_m1 << 23) + mant_a + ((rndstk | (mant_a & 1)) > 0x80000000);` 
[2] `r = (expo_a_m1 << 23) + mant_a + (rndstk >= 0x80000000); if (rndstk == 0x80000000) r = r & ~1;` 
[3] `r = (expo_a_m1 << 23) + mant_a + ((rndstk == 0x80000000) ? (mant_a & 1) : (rndstk >> 31));`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. If you want to write an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The rounding byte is (as the name suggests) a full 8 bits, so I was originally shifting the carry in and then ORing with the LSB of the original value. So there were 7 round/guard bits and 1 sticky bit. I hear you on the rounding bias. I will probably go back and make it round ties to even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes the use of one of the IEEE-754 binary floating-point types, e.g. `binary32`, `binary64`.

If we look at the significand just prior to rounding, so *after* a possible re-normalization (when significand was outside the range [1, 2) after significand addition or multiplication) or denormalization (for tentatively subnormal results), rounding requires three pieces of information when rounding to nearest, *ties-to-even*: The round bit `R`, which is basically an additional significand bit with numeric weight half of the least significant stored significand bit, the sticky "bit" `S` that is the implicit OR of all significand bits of numerically lower weight than the round bit, and the least significand bit of the significand, `L`.

Outside of tie cases, `R` alone decides whether the significant needs to be incremented (when `R==1`) or not. In a tie case, where the infinitely precise intermediate result is exactly half-way between the two closest representable significand values, we have `R==1` and `S==0` and need to examine `L` to satisfy the ties-to-even provision. In summary, the significand needs to be incremented when `(R==1) && ((S==1) || (L==1))`.

As alluded to in the question, this rounding logic is simplified when using the rounding mode round to nearest, *ties-to-away*. The significand needs to be incremented when `(R==1) && ((S==X) || (L==X))` (where `X` means: don't care) as one does not need to distinguish the cases of discarded bits representing a value greater than 0.5 ulp or exactly equal to 0.5 ulp, and there is no need to examine the significand to see whether it is even. We are left with `R==1` as the only condition for incrementing the significand, and there is no need to accumulate sticky "bit" information.

I used the term sticky "bit" because in software emulations it is standard practice to dedicate one register to the round and sticky information, with the most significant bit of the register representing the round bit and all lower order bits *collectively* representing (by implicit OR) the sticky information. This saves the effort of condensing the sticky information into a single bit in a particular location. When one uses a rounding byte as mentioned in the question, the conditional incrementation of the significand is based on either comparison of the rounding byte with `0x80`, or by adding `0x80` or `0x7F` (depending on the flavor of round to nearest used) and propagating the carry.

Because round to nearest, ties-to-even implements *unbiased* rounding, while round to nearest, ties-to-away does not, I would strongly recommend implementing the former mode, despite the slightly higher cost. This is also useful for maintaining compatibility with other platforms.

Below I am showing emulation code for IEEE-754 `binary32` addition and multiplication that demonstrates that maintaining the sticky information and implementing ties-to-even adds less than 10% overhead, and this should hold for emulation on a byte-oriented processor. Three different algorithms for the actual rounding to nearest with *ties-to-even* are shown. Which approach works best will depend on specifics of the platform; I have used all three variants in the past. My apologies for the inconsistencies: The two pieces of code were written at different times, in different contexts, and in somewhat differing styles. Note that this code uses a 32-bit rounding word rather than a rounding byte since the code was written for a 32-bit platform.

Code for `binary32` addition, with the rounding word in variable `rdnstk`:

```c
#define RND_VARIANT (3)  // 1 ... 3
#define CLZ_VARIANT (4)  // 1 ... 5

int clz (uint32_t a);

uint32_t fp32_add_rn_kernel (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    /* sort arguments my magnitude. Larger one becomes a, smaller becomes b */
    if ((b << 1) > (a << 1)) {
        uint32_t t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }

    uint32_t expo_a_m1 = ((a >> 23) & 0xff) - 1;
    uint32_t expo_b_m1 = ((b >> 23) & 0xff) - 1;

    if ((expo_a_m1 >= 0xfe) || (expo_b_m1 >= 0xfe)) {
        uint32_t am = a << 1;
        uint32_t bm = b << 1;
        if (bm == 0) {                // b is zero
            if (am == 0) a = a & b;   // a is also zero
            if (am > 0xff000000) a = a | 0x00400000; // a is NaN, quieten it
            return a;
        } else if ((expo_b_m1 > 0xfe) &&  // b is subnormal
                   (expo_a_m1 != 0xfe)) { // a is not NaN or INF
            int shift = clz (bm) - 8;
            bm = bm << shift;
            expo_b_m1 = ~shift;
            b = (b & 0x80000000) | bm;
            if (expo_a_m1 > 0xfe) { // a is subnormal
                int shift = clz (am) - 8;
                am = am << shift;
                expo_a_m1 = ~shift;
                a = (a & 0x80000000) | am;
            }
        } else if (am > 0xff000000) {     // a is a NaN
            return a | 0x00400000;
        } else if (bm > 0xff000000) {     // b is a NaN
            return b | 0x00400000;
        } else if ((am & bm) == 0xff000000) { // a is INF and b is INF
            return a | ((a ^ b) ? 0xffc00000 : 0);
        } else if ((am == 0) || (bm == 0xff000000)) { // a is zero or b is INF
            return b;
        } else if ((bm == 0) || (am == 0xff000000)) { // b is zero or a is INF
            return a;
        } 
    }
    uint32_t expo_diff = expo_a_m1 - expo_b_m1;
    uint32_t sign_a = a & 0x80000000;
    uint32_t r;
    if (expo_diff <= 25) {  
        uint32_t mant_a = (a & 0x00ffffff) | 0x00800000; // add in implict bit
        uint32_t mant_b = (b & 0x00ffffff) | 0x00800000; // add in implict bit
        uint32_t rndstk = expo_diff ? (mant_b << (32 - expo_diff)) : 0;
        if ((int32_t)(a ^ b) < 0) { // effective subtraction
            rndstk = 0 - rndstk;
            mant_a = mant_a - (mant_b >> expo_diff) - (rndstk != 0);
            if (!(mant_a & 0x00800000)) { /* cancellation of leading bits */
                if ((mant_a | rndstk) == 0) {
                    return mant_a; /* addends cancel completely */
                }
                /* renormalize */
                uint32_t shift = clz (mant_a) - 8;
                mant_a = (mant_a << shift) | (rndstk >> (32 - shift));
                rndstk <<= shift;
                expo_a_m1 -= shift;
            }
        } else {
            mant_a = mant_a + (mant_b >> expo_diff);
            if (mant_a & 0x01000000) { // significand overflow, renormalize
                rndstk = (rndstk >> 1) | (mant_a << 31);
                mant_a = mant_a >> 1;
                expo_a_m1 += 1;
            }
        }
        if (expo_a_m1 < 0xfe) {
            /* normal: round to nearest or even */
#if RND_VARIANT == 1
            r = (expo_a_m1 << 23) + mant_a + 
                ((rndstk | (mant_a & 1)) > 0x80000000);
#elif RND_VARIANT == 2
            r = (expo_a_m1 << 23) + mant_a + (rndstk >= 0x80000000);
            if (rndstk == 0x80000000) r = r & ~1; // tie case
#elif RND_VARIANT == 3
            r = (expo_a_m1 << 23) + mant_a + 
                ((rndstk == 0x80000000) ? (mant_a & 1) : (rndstk >> 31));
#else // RND_VARIANT
#error unsupported RND_VARIANT
#endif // RND_VARIANT 
        } else if (expo_a_m1 > 0xfe) { // underflow
            int denorm_shift = 0 - expo_a_m1;
            r = mant_a >> denorm_shift;
        } else { // overflow
            r = 0x7f800000;
        }
    } else {
        r = a;
    }
    r = sign_a | r;
    return r;
}

int clz (uint32_t a)
{
#if CLZ_VARIANT == 1
    static const uint8_t clz_tab[32] = {
        31, 22, 30, 21, 18, 10, 29,  2, 20, 17, 15, 13, 9,  6, 28, 1,
        23, 19, 11,  3, 16, 14,  7, 24, 12,  4,  8, 25, 5, 26, 27, 0
    };
    a |= a >> 16;
    a |= a >> 8;
    a |= a >> 4;
    a |= a >> 2;
    a |= a >> 1;
    return clz_tab [0x07c4acddu * a >> 27] + (!a);
#elif CLZ_VARIANT == 2
    uint32_t b;
    int n = 31 + (!a);
    if ((b = (a & 0xffff0000u))) { n -= 16;  a = b; }
    if ((b = (a & 0xff00ff00u))) { n -=  8;  a = b; }
    if ((b = (a & 0xf0f0f0f0u))) { n -=  4;  a = b; }
    if ((b = (a & 0xccccccccu))) { n -=  2;  a = b; }
    if ((    (a & 0xaaaaaaaau))) { n -=  1;         }
    return n;
#elif CLZ_VARIANT == 3
    int n = 0;
    if (!(a & 0xffff0000u)) { n |= 16;  a <<= 16; }
    if (!(a & 0xff000000u)) { n |=  8;  a <<=  8; }
    if (!(a & 0xf0000000u)) { n |=  4;  a <<=  4; }
    if (!(a & 0xc0000000u)) { n |=  2;  a <<=  2; }
    if ((int32_t)a >= 0) n++;
    if ((int32_t)a == 0) n++;
    return n;
#elif CLZ_VARIANT == 4
    uint32_t b;
    int n = 32;
    if ((b = (a >> 16))) { n = n - 16;  a = b; }
    if ((b = (a >>  8))) { n = n -  8;  a = b; }
    if ((b = (a >>  4))) { n = n -  4;  a = b; }
    if ((b = (a >>  2))) { n = n -  2;  a = b; }
    if ((b = (a >>  1))) return n - 2;
    return n - a;
#elif CLZ_VARIANT == 5
    return __builtin_clz (a);
#else
#error unknown CLZ_VARIANT
#endif
}

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a)
{
    uint32_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

float uint32_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

float fp32_add_rn (float a, float b)
{
    uint32_t ai, bi;

    ai = float_as_uint32 (a);
    bi = float_as_uint32 (b);
    return uint32_as_float (fp32_add_rn_kernel (ai, bi));
}
```

This is the emulation of `binary32` multiplication, with the rounding word in variable `mantr_lo`:

```c
#define RND_VARIANT (3)     // 1 ... 3

#define FLOAT_MANT_BITS    (23)
#define FLOAT_EXPO_BITS    (8)
#define FLOAT_EXPO_BIAS    (127)
#define FLOAT_MANT_MASK    (~((~0u) << (FLOAT_MANT_BITS+1))) /* incl. integer bit */
#define EXPO_ADJUST        (1)   /* adjustment for performance reasons */
#define MIN_NORM_EXPO      (1)   /* minimum biased exponent of normals */
#define MAX_NORM_EXPO      (254) /* maximum biased exponent of normals */
#define INF_EXPO           (255) /* biased exponent of infinities */
#define EXPO_MASK          (~((~0u) << FLOAT_EXPO_BITS))
#define FLOAT_SIGN_MASK    (0x80000000u)
#define FLOAT_IMPLICIT_BIT (1 << FLOAT_MANT_BITS)
#define RND_BIT_SHIFT      (31)
#define RND_BIT_MASK       (1 << RND_BIT_SHIFT)
#define FLOAT_INFINITY     (0x7f800000)
#define FLOAT_INDEFINITE   (0xffc00000u)
#define MANT_LSB           (0x00000001)
#define FLOAT_QNAN_BIT     (0x00400000)
#define MAX_SHIFT          (FLOAT_MANT_BITS + 2)

uint32_t fp32_mul_core (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    uint64_t prod;
    uint32_t expoa, expob, manta, mantb, shift;
    uint32_t r, signr, expor, mantr_hi, mantr_lo;

    /* split arguments into sign, exponent, significand */
    expoa = ((a >> FLOAT_MANT_BITS) & EXPO_MASK) - EXPO_ADJUST;
    expob = ((b >> FLOAT_MANT_BITS) & EXPO_MASK) - EXPO_ADJUST;
    manta = (a | FLOAT_IMPLICIT_BIT) & FLOAT_MANT_MASK;
    mantb = (b | FLOAT_IMPLICIT_BIT) & FLOAT_MANT_MASK;
    /* result sign bit: XOR sign argument signs */
    signr = (a ^ b) & FLOAT_SIGN_MASK;
    if ((expoa >= (MAX_NORM_EXPO - EXPO_ADJUST)) || /* at least one argument is special */
        (expob >= (MAX_NORM_EXPO - EXPO_ADJUST))) { 
        if ((a & ~FLOAT_SIGN_MASK) > FLOAT_INFINITY) { /* a is NaN */
            /* return quietened NaN */
            return a | FLOAT_QNAN_BIT;
        }
        if ((b & ~FLOAT_SIGN_MASK) > FLOAT_INFINITY) { /* b is NaN */
            /* return quietened NaN */
            return b | FLOAT_QNAN_BIT;
        }
        if ((a & ~FLOAT_SIGN_MASK) == 0) { /* a is zero */
            /* return NaN if b is infinity, else zero */
            return (expob != (INF_EXPO - EXPO_ADJUST)) ? signr : FLOAT_INDEFINITE;
        }
        if ((b & ~FLOAT_SIGN_MASK) == 0) { /* b is zero */
            /* return NaN if a is infinity, else zero */
            return (expoa != (INF_EXPO - EXPO_ADJUST)) ? signr : FLOAT_INDEFINITE;
        }
        if (((a & ~FLOAT_SIGN_MASK) == FLOAT_INFINITY) || /* a or b infinity */
            ((b & ~FLOAT_SIGN_MASK) == FLOAT_INFINITY)) {
            return signr | FLOAT_INFINITY;
        }
        if ((int32_t)expoa < (MIN_NORM_EXPO - EXPO_ADJUST)) { /* a is subnormal */
            /* normalize significand of a */
            manta = a & FLOAT_MANT_MASK;
            expoa++;
            do {
                manta = 2 * manta;
                expoa--;
            } while (manta < FLOAT_IMPLICIT_BIT);
        } else if ((int32_t)expob < (MIN_NORM_EXPO - EXPO_ADJUST)) { /* b is subnormal */
            /* normalize significand of b */
            mantb = b & FLOAT_MANT_MASK;
            expob++;
            do {
                mantb = 2 * mantb;
                expob--;
            } while (mantb < FLOAT_IMPLICIT_BIT);
        }
    }
    /* result exponent: add argument exponents and adjust for biasing */
    expor = expoa + expob - FLOAT_EXPO_BIAS + 2 * EXPO_ADJUST;
    mantb = mantb << FLOAT_EXPO_BITS; /* preshift to align result signficand */
    /* result significand: multiply argument significands */
    prod = (uint64_t)manta * mantb;
    mantr_hi = (uint32_t)(prod >> 32);
    mantr_lo = (uint32_t)(prod >>  0);
    /* normalize significand */
    if (mantr_hi < FLOAT_IMPLICIT_BIT) {
        mantr_hi = (mantr_hi << 1) | (mantr_lo >> (32 - 1));
        mantr_lo = (mantr_lo << 1);
        expor--;
    }
    if (expor <= (MAX_NORM_EXPO - EXPO_ADJUST)) { /* normal, may overflow to infinity during rounding */
        /* combine biased exponent, sign and signficand */
        r = (expor << FLOAT_MANT_BITS) + signr + mantr_hi;
        /* round result to nearest or even; overflow to infinity possible */
#if RND_VARIANT == 1
        r = r + ((mantr_lo | (mantr_hi & MANT_LSB)) > RND_BIT_MASK);
#elif RND_VARIANT == 2
        r = r + (mantr_lo >= RND_BIT_MASK);
        if (mantr_lo == 0x80000000) r = r & ~MANT_LSB; // tie case
#elif RND_VARIANT == 3
        r = r + ((mantr_lo == RND_BIT_MASK) ? (mantr_hi & MANT_LSB) : (mantr_lo >> RND_BIT_SHIFT));
#else // RND_VARIANT
#error unsupported RND_VARIANT
#endif // RND_VARIANT 
    } else if ((int32_t)expor > (MAX_NORM_EXPO - EXPO_ADJUST)) { /* overflow */
        /* return infinity */
        r = signr | FLOAT_INFINITY;
    } else { /* underflow */
        /* return zero, normal, or smallest subnormal */
        shift = 0 - expor;
        if (shift > MAX_SHIFT) shift = MAX_SHIFT;
        /* denormalize significand */
        mantr_lo = mantr_hi << (32 - shift) | (mantr_lo ? 1 : 0);
        mantr_hi = mantr_hi >> shift;
        /* combine sign and signficand; biased exponent known to be zero */
        r = mantr_hi + signr;
        /* round result to nearest or even */
#if RND_VARIANT == 1
        r = r + ((mantr_lo | (mantr_hi & MANT_LSB)) > RND_BIT_MASK);
#elif RND_VARIANT == 2
        r = r + (mantr_lo >= RND_BIT_MASK);
        if (mantr_lo == 0x80000000) r = r & ~MANT_LSB; // tie case
#elif RND_VARIANT == 3
        r = r + ((mantr_lo == RND_BIT_MASK) ? (mantr_hi & MANT_LSB) : (mantr_lo >> RND_BIT_SHIFT));
#else // RND_VARIANT
#error unsupported RND_VARIANT
#endif // RND_VARIANT 
     }
    return r;
}

uint32_t float_as_uint (float a)
{
    uint32_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

float uint_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

float fp32_mul (float a, float b)
{
    return uint_as_float (fp32_mul_core (float_as_uint (a), float_as_uint (b)));
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! If you know the answer, it would be nice to include some info on when a guard bit would be necessary, since your answer states that all bit the most significant bits can be sticky bits.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn Ever since I wrote my first floating-point emulation package around 1987 I found this "guard bit" terminology confusing and don't use it. Simply keep in mind that re-normalization may be necessary prior to rounding to get the significant into 1<=s<2  (when result is in normal range). That may involve left shift or right shift as appropriate. Once the significand is normalized, we need a round "bit" and a sticky "bit" for rounding purpose. They may not be actual bits, see [division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690647/correctly-rounded-double-precision-division)

Comment: The argument for the guard bit is that may be shifted left into the significand during normalization. But what I don't understand is the assumption that only one bit will need to be shifted. What if normalization requires shifting left two places? Then both the guard and round will be shifted in. I suspect I'm missing something here but don't know what it is.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn I think you are confirming my take that the guard bit concept is more confusing than helpful. Larger left shifts can only happen after effective subtraction, in particular when both operands have the same exponent. In those cases there are no information-carrying bits below the LSB of the significand, and the result is exact (see also: Sterbenz Lemma). You can instrument the code around the comment "cancellation of leading bits" in the `fp32_add` emulation to visualize what is going on.