# Clarification on IEEE 754 rounding to nearest, ties to even

Tags: floating-point, rounding, ieee-754, half-precision-float

I am working on an IEEE 754 16-bit adder, and I am confused at the round to nearest, ties to even logic.

The first addition which confuses me is 169.8 (`0x594E`) + -0.06256 (`0xAC01`).

After shifting and adding (subtracting), my untrimmed mantissa is calculated to be `01010011011000000000`

Splitting into guard, round, and sticky bits: `0101001101 | 1 (guard) | 0 (round) | 0 (sticky)`

From my understanding, since my GSR bits are `100`, this is a tie, and I use the LSB of the mantissa (`1`) to round the final mantissa to `0101001110`, resulting in a final result of 169.8 (`0x594E`).  However, my UVM testbench and online IEEE calculators give the result as 169.6 (`0x594D`).

---

I then tested a second test case, -1.067E4 (`0xF136`) + 2554.0 (`0x68FD`).

Using the same shift and add (subtract again), my untrimmed mantissa is `11111011011000000000`

Splitting again as above: `1111101101 | 1 (guard) | 0 (round) | 0 (sticky)` (same as earlier)

However, this time, when I increment the fraction to `1111101110` using the same logic, this is apparently correct, with a result of -8120.0 (`0xEFEE`).

I feel like I am misunderstanding the logic for determining when to round to nearest even, or I am handling the rounding incorrectly.

Comment: I remember that this whole GSR business was more confusing than helpful when I first implemented IEEE-754 in the 1980s. IHMO a better way to expresses round-to-nearest even rounding: Call the least significant bit of the significand "odd", the next *less significant* bit "round", and the logical OR of all even less significant bits "sticky". Then for RNE: `significand += (round & (sticky | odd))`. See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74792768/floating-point-can-i-skip-the-sticky-bit-if-i-am-only-rounding-ties-to-away)

Comment: What do you mean by “16-bit adder”? Do you mean the floating-point format is 1-5-10, 1 sign bit, 5 exponent bits, 10 primary significand bits? If so, then the pre-rounding significand is not (1)01010011011000000000… 10 primary significand bits means the mathematical significand (the preferred term; “mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm) is 11 bits. 169.8 is binary is 1010 1001.1100 1100 1…, so rounding it to 11 bits produces 1010 1001.110. −0.06256 is −.0001 0000 0000 0011…, so rounding it to 11 significant bits produces −.0001 0000 0000 01. Then…

Comment: … adding those two numbers produces 1010 1001.1010 1111…, not 1010 1001.1011 0… Then rounding to 11 significant digits produces 1010 1001.101, which is 169.625.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for the sanity check.  I think the error stems from not storing enough intermediate calculation bits during the addition, which resulted in my confusion earlier.  Lesson learned about working with too little sleep.